# Can we set alert on no of messages in anypoint mq queues?

Tags: mule, mule-component

I have a requirement, where I need to send an alert, when no of messages reach in mq queues.

Can we set an alert in [Anypoint Message Queue](https://www.mulesoft.com/de/platform/anypoint-mq-message-queue)?

Comment: Could you please clarify, what exactly you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can set this from your MQ management tool. [Click here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/techarticles/1311_jin/1311_jin.html) to know more details.

Comment: Sorry I missed to notice that. But for anypoint mq there is no such configuration for setting notification.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure, what you want to achieve, but if you would like to access some message queue related statistics, then you could use the [MQ Statistics API](https://docs.mulesoft.com/anypoint-mq/mq-apis#mqstatapi).

Using the API you can access different statistics, that could be interesting for you based on your question:

> As of Anypoint MQ 1.7.4 release, these statistics are provided:
>
> ```
> messagesVisible - The number of messages that can be retrieved from a queue.
>
> messagesSent - The number of messages added to a queue.
>
> messagesReceived - The number of messages received in a queue.
>
> messagesAcked - The number of messages ACKed. Also includes any messages deleted using the Anypoint Platform > MQ user interface.
> ```

I hope I have helped.